# Showing ieee 754 Representation of Decimal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, ieee-754, ieee

I am trying to show the ieee 754 representations of decimals. I have seen various threads saying that the numbers are already in ieee 754 double precision but I can't seem to get them to look right.

For example, if I enter 0.07 in here https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html I get 0.070000000298. I am trying to replicate this in javascript without jquery.

I need it to be able to show things like this:

```
0.07 = 0.070000000298023223876953125
0.0245 = 0.02449999935925006866455078125
0.5 = 0.5000000000000000000000000000
```

If anyone has a suggestion, it will be much appreciated! Thanks

edit: the tool is using 32-bit floating point representation

Comment: IEEE 754 is a **binary** floating-point format.

Comment: Also note that that tool is showing you 32-bit floating point representation; JavaScript numbers are 64-bit.

Comment: May simply look into the pages sourcecode? Just saying...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am kind of new to javascript and don't understand if javascript being 64 bit is an issue. Thanks you for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, decimal numbers are represented in IEEE754 double precision (64 bits).

https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html works with IEEE754 single precision (32 bits) numbers.

To convert a number in IEEE754 single precision you can use Float32Array:

```
const foo = 0.07
const foo32bits = Float32Array.from([foo])[0]

// foo === 0.07
// foo32bits = 0.07000000029802322
```

You can also use `Math.fround()`:

```js
Math.fround(0.07) // 0.07000000029802322
```